# Why does soup.find() not find a paragraph with specifc text?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing an HTML file using Python and BeautifulSoup, looking for a paragraph with specific text using `soup.find()`. `soup.find()` fails to find the paragraph, but when I iterate over all of the paragraphs and test each paragraph for the specific text, I can confirm that it's there.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
# start returns as an empty list
pattern = "Text to find"
start = soup.find("p", text=pattern)

# Iterating over all of the paragrapcs and testing each one
# yields the paragraph I'm looking for

ps = soup.find_all('p')
for p in ps:
    line=p.sourceline
    if p.text == pattern:
        print(p.sourceline)
```

Comment: What is the value of `pattern`?

Comment: Woops - messed up the fromatting......  pattern is the text I'm looking for - I updated the original question so that's clear now

Comment: I also tried different parsers - html5lib and lxml - neither helped

Comment: Don't you want `.find_all()`, not `.find()`?

Comment: I'm looking for the first paragraph that includes the target string - so .find() seems appropriate?

Comment: I just tried .find_all() and it didn't return anything either

Comment: `.find()` doesn't return a list, it returns either the single result or `None`. How did you determine that `.find()` wasn't working? Did you try to (incorrectly) iterate through the result, or did you print out the returned value? Also, can you give an example of the `<p>` tag you are looking for?

Comment: In the aboce example, start is None after the find('p', text=pattern) call. I can see this in my IDE (PyCharm)

Comment: Here's the tag  - the actual pattern I'm looking for is 'Case Control Command Summary'    <p dir="ltr" class="FM_h1"><a name="TOC_Case_Control_Command1"></a><a name="XREF_21097_Case_Control"></a>Case Control Command Summary</p>

Answer (score 1):

You could try using :-soup-contains

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<p dir="ltr" class="FM_h1"><a name="TOC_Case_Control_Command1"></a><a name="XREF_21097_Case_Control"></a>Case Control Command Summary</p>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Case Control Command Summary")'))
```